# Basic user log out with correct redirection - Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, logout

I have created a basic log in for my app, `login.php`. It looks like this:

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'app_secret' => 'YYYYYYYYYYYY',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
        ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['user_hometown']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost:8080/myapp/fb-callback.php', $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
```

I'm now trying to add a logout link to `fb-callback.php`, to allow the user to log out from the app, but it's not working correctly - it redirects me to Facebook page instead of `login.php` on my localhost.

What am I doing wrong?

See the last lines of `fb-callback.php` for logout :

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'app_secret' => 'YYYYYYYYYYYY',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
        ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (! isset($accessToken)) {
  if ($helper->getError()) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
    echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
    echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
    echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
  } else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    echo 'Bad request';
  }
  exit;
}


$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=hometown', $accessToken);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$user = $response->getGraphUser();

echo 'Hometown: ' . $user->getHometown()->getField('name'). "<br>";


$logoutUrl = $helper->getLogoutUrl('{access-token}', 'http://localhost:8080/myapp/login.php');
echo '<a href="' . $logoutUrl . '">Logout of Facebook!</a>';
```

Also, is there a way to not display the user's access token in the URL after redirecting from `login` to `fb-callback`?

Comment: You did replace `{access-token}` with the actual user access token, right?

Comment: @CBroe sure, I did